# Wi-Fi Network setup

Tags: wireless

I tried to set up Wi-Fi connection from my Ubuntu 14.04 to my Android phone(samsung gt duos GT-18262). I want to access Internet connection from my phone on to my Laptop. There fore I installed *kde-nm-connection-editor* and choosed “Wireless (shared)” from the drop-down list, and then typed in a name, ssid, and selected  ***Access Point*** mode, and set up a password under ***Wireless Security*** tab. And when I finally tried to click O.K the tab is not high lighted ,which means I couldn't complete my settings and hence I cannot set up a wireless connection. How do I solve it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your android phone as *HotSpot*, then in the usual menu of *wifi connections* in ubuntu you can see your device and connect. 
How to set up HotSpot:[*here*](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=make+hotspot++android&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=MF9TVIy5HcXM8ge1zYCADA)

Comment: Thanks ,man it worked. But I cannot access the internet. How do I access from my phone?